# Как сделать так чтобы из одного сокета могли читать несколько потоков?

Tags: c++, распараллеливание

Задача - максимально просто и наглядно реализовать распределенные вычисления.
На вход сокету должен приходить блок для вычисления, сокет должен напрямую или опосредованно передавать части блока в n параллельных процессов на обработку, ждать завершения всех и отправлять обратно. Язык C++11.

Какие библиотеки и принципы архитектуры желательно использовать?

Единственное что покуда нарыл - I/O Completion Ports, но не уверен что это здесь к месту.

Вот [здесь](http://www.coderanch.com/t/207132/sockets/java/Multiple-threads-writing-reading-single) очень близкая задача описана.

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял из вопроса, данные будут приходить только от одного клиента и отправляться туда же. Если это так, то для работы с сетью нет никакой насущной необходимости использовать I/O Completion Ports (тем более, что это платформозависимое решение). Самым простым и рабочим будет использование обычных блокирующих сокетов. После вычитки данных с сокета разобъете их на нужные блоки. Распараллеливание можете выполнить посредством [std::launch](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/launch/).

Comment: В идеале, я хотел бы получить что вроде - "попробуй использовать #include"lib_name1.hpp" и #include"lib_name2.hpp". Но это в идеале.

Comment: @просто_прогер Понятно Ваше желание, но для того же распараллеливания используется стандартная функция. Что же может быть проще? Какие лишние инклюды? Ну а передача по сети данных не намного сложнее. Примеров просто тьма.

Answer (score 2):

Для параллельных вычислений на одной многоядерной машине - OpenMP.

Для параллельных вычислений на сети машин - OpenMPI.

**Попытки самостоятельно реализовать вышеперечисленные каркасы оканчиваются веселым ловом багов в параллельном коде.**

[Пример кода](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/mpi/sum_mpi.c)

Данный пример делает следующее:

Узел номер 0 формирует массив из чисел.

После этого все узлы (в том числе и 0) вычисляют сумму элементов этого массива, умноженных на номер соответствующего узла

Затем узлы отсылают узлу номер 0 полученные суммы.

Сервер эти суммы также суммирует и выдает итог.

Возьмите любую вузовскую презентацию-учебник по OpenMPI и получите желаемое.

*Также из экзотики:*

GNU Parallel - позволяет организовать вычисления, используя только STDIO, не написав ни капли сетевого кода

Для ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО БОЛЬШИХ вычислений - HADOOP.

Kerrighed - уже подзабытый (ядро 2.6) способ получить в пределах кучи машин один линукс, который будет видеть суммарную память и суммарное число ядер всех машин.

OrangeFS (в девичестве pvfs2) - распределенная файловая система, по простоте развертывания сравнимая с табуреткой. Имеет, что удивительно, клиент под Windows. Что не удивительно, данный клиент не работает с русскими буквами в именах файлах. Надо исправить там одну функцию, так что ждем ебилдов. Разбивает файл на N узлов хранения, позволяя тем самым добиться 1 гигабайта в секунду скорости отдачи | получения данных на десятке таких узлов хранения.

Comment: Пушками по воробьям?

Comment: @MaxZS пушками по воробьям - это сидеть и кропать часами сетевой и потоковый код, вместо четырех вызовов MPI_*, два из которых - инициализация и очистка.

Comment: А собственно работа с сокетами в MPI включена? Я имею в виду, что я видел примеры работы MPI только для одного ядра либо  с условным "вот здесь мы как то получаем данные"

Comment: Т.е. время на изучение этих библиотек Вы не считаете? Думаете, что их можно освоить моментально? Да и кропать часами сетевой и потоковый коды, при такой постановке задачи, точно не придется. Считаете, что на распараллеливание кода, использую одну стандартную функцию, требуются часы? Или часы требуются на написание кода получения данных из одного сокета?

Comment: @просто_прогер MPI полностью берет на себя ответственность за обмен данными между узлами кластера и их синхронизацию. О сокетах и TCP ничего знать не нужно.

Comment: @gbg Спасибо! А можно(сорри за некоторое нахальство, и так сильно помогли) - пруф на пример где допустим сеть из 3-4 клиентов и сервер...

Comment: @просто_прогер обмен данными между узлами реализуйте на MPI. Параллельную работу на одном узле - при помощи OpenMP.

Comment: @просто_прогер в MPI нет понятия "сервер", формально, все узлы там равноправны. Обычно, в качестве заправителя выступает узел с номером 0. Ссылку на пример я добавил в ответ.

Comment: @gbg ссылки  не вижу, увы

Comment: @просто_прогер обновите страницу.